# Print an image in html using session variable from php

Tags: php, html, session-variables

i have this code trying to print an image in an html using 
session variable from a php.Here is my code:

```
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_id(1);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['phname'];
?>
<img src="../uploads/$_SESSION['phname']" alt="photo" width="498" height="720" border="0" />
```

here:

```
session_id(1);
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['phname'];
```

i'm checking if my variable has passed 
  from the php and its ok.
  and here

```
?>
<img src="../uploads/$_SESSION['phname']" alt="photo" width="498" height="720" border="0" />
```

i'm using php to print the image from the following source

```
src="../uploads/$_SESSION['phname']"
```

when $_SESSION['phname'] is my image's name  but i'm not getting the image.  Is there something wrong with my code or 
   is there any other way to print my image?
   i try a lot of things and a lot of codes 
   i found on the net but nothing help me more.

Comment: What actually gets rendered in the src attribute?

Comment: Your image path is not even inside any PHP-tag, so obviously $_SESSION[...] doesn't even get evaluated by PHP. Try replacing it with `<img src="../uploads/<?PHP echo $_SESSION['phname']; ?>" alt="photo" width="498" height="720" border="0" />
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your `session_start` before you output anything to the browser as it sends some headers.

And of course when you want to echo something in php, you need php tags and an `echo` statement...

Answer (score 3):

```
<?session_start();?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_id(1);

echo $_SESSION['phname'];

echo "<img src=\"../uploads/". $_SESSION['phname']."\" alt=\"photo\" width=\"498\" height="720" border="0" />";
?>
```